# Mixed ANOVA: small and unbalanced samples

Tags: anova, sample-size, small-sample, unbalanced-classes, mixed-model

I have to analyze two samples ($n_1=10, n_2=18$) in a design in which there is a between-subject factor (`Groups`: 2 levels) and a within-subjects factor (`Stimuli`: 2 levels). I'm wondering if, in such situations, a mixed (between/within) ANOVA is justified, given the small and unbalanced samples size. The rule of thumb for ANOVA is at least 30 subjects for cell, I know, but often I read papers in which ANOVA is used for smaller samples.

**Could anyone suggests me the best practice for this situation? Can such analysis in this context be defended in a publication process?**

Comment: what is your model? can you describe it using [standard notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_model)?